Why does my baked textures normal look puffy?
Why does my baked textures normal and diffuse looks puffy like its not sharp like the high poly object?
I'm trying to make a high poly ornament onto a flat plane and its driving me crazy how it looks kinda puffy
high poly mesh:

Flat plane with baked texture:

Baked diffuse map on plane:


The bake is using the UV map of the mesh and has some additional margin to ensure each face is completely covered by the baked image.

So do I have to unwrap the high poly mesh? Or do I have to add loop cuts to the plane?

Margin is not a problem. As for your last image, maybe show your Shader Editor node setup to see if something is incorrect?

I think i figured it out! I just had to turn down the margins value in the bake. It doesn't matter for the normal map but I guess it matter for the diffuse map if I want it to look exactly like the high poly shape!
